# Add an object to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a `settings.json` file that contains following data (where `123456789` is a distinct user id):

```
{
 "123456789":
   {"button_mode":true}
}
```

So what I need to do is push a similar `id: {button_mode: value}` object to this JSON file in case there's no entry for current user's id. I tried to use `lcSettings.push()` but obviously it did not work since I have an object, not an array. When I put square brackets instead of curly ones to make it an array, my code doesn't do anything at all.
Here's a snippet of it (Node.js):

```
var lcSettings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./settings.json', 'utf8'));
var currentUser = id;
if (lcSettings.hasOwnProperty(currentUser)) {
   // in case settings.json contains current user's id check for button_mode state
   if (lcSettings[currentUser].button_mode == true) {
      // if button_mode is on
   } else
   if (lcSettings[currentUser].button_mode == false) {
      // if button_mode is off
   }
} else {
   // in case there's no entry for current user's id
   // here's where I need to push the object for new user.
}
fs.writeFileSync('./settings.json', JSON.stringify(lcSettings))
```

Does anybody have ideas on how it can be implemented? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to add a dynamic property to an object:

```
lcSettings[id] = { button_mode: false };
```

You may also want to verify that `settings.json` is not empty otherwise the `JSON.parse()` will fail. In this case, you would want to initialize `lcSettings` to an empty object (`lcSettings = {}`) so the above will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked.
The `settings.json` wasn't empty (I'd get `Unexpected end of JSON input` otherwise, right?).

Answer (score 1):

To 'push' elements to an object you simply define them, as in

```
object['123456789'] = { button_mode: true };
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could mark both your and Anthony's answers as correct.

Comment: @llgdd in addition to marking an answer correct, you can also upvote multiple answers if they are also correct and/or have some other additional information

Comment: @Anthony they don't have 15 reputation yet tho